# HTML: Adding picture with link to slideshow of images with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

So I have a slideshow on my website with images with no links. It also has buttons on the bottom to navigate to the other pictures, one for each image. I am trying to add another image, this one with a link to another part of the website. I would believe to add the picture 
to the list of 

`<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-01.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">" 
<img src="/images/home-slideshow/photo-02.jpg" alt="" width="684" height="325">"`
"
I would just add the same but add 

`<a href="website.com"><img src="/image/home-slideshow/photo-06.jpg" alt="" width ="684" height="325"></a>`

The question I had was is there anything else I have to change somewhere else? 
Also, I have to add a button for that image, would adding this linked photo to the slideshow affect the buttons in some weird way?

EDIT:
here is my slideshow javascript. But it doesnt look like it makes them strictly images?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Show the paging and activate its first link
$(".paging").show();
$(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

//Get size of the image, how many images there are, then determine the size of the image reel.
var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

//Adjust the image reel to its new size
$(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

//Paging  and Slider Function
rotate = function(){
    var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

    $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
    $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

    //Slider Animation
    $(".image_reel").animate({
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500 );

}; 

//Rotation  and Timing Event
rotateSwitch = function(){
    play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 7 seconds
        $active = $('.paging a.active').next(); //Move to the next paging
        if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
            $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
        }
        rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
    }, 7000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (7 seconds)
};

rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

//On Hover
$(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
}, function() {
    rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation timer
}); 

//On Click
$(".paging a").click(function() {
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    //Reset Timer
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation timer
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});
```

});

Comment: Without seeing your JS, we can't help you. From what you described, I would think the JS is looking only for `img` elements. (Also, please use CSS for the `height` and `width`. It's cleaner and smaller.)

Comment: Have you tested your theory? It sounds like you haven't actually tried anything.

Comment: It seems like your assumptions are correct: just add the image in an <a> tag, and the technically-unrelated buttons below won't be affected. You can even alter that image so it says "click me" or has the image of a button on it, to encourage the user to click it. But as Mooseman said, we can't be sure if it will work until we see your JS code.

Comment: @user3734797 You should add tags for JQuery and JavaScript to your question. This isn't just HTML. In fact I can read HTML (and JavaScript) great, but I don't know JQuery so I can't help much.